# In how many ways can the integers from $1$ to $n$ be divided into two groups with the same sum?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, integers

In how many ways can the integers $1,2,\ldots,n$ be divided into two groups with the same sum?

I have tried calculating some of these values for small $n$, but cannot seem to find a pattern.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Sometimes none, when $n$ is of shape $4k+1$ or $4k+2$.

Comment: I don't think I can help, but what exactly is your question?  Given a sum, how many subsets of size two of $\{1...n\}$ give this sum?  Or is it how many distinct sums are given from grouping two of each of the first $n$ integers (including 1?)?

Comment: I don't know if I can make it more clear, but I can provide an example: for $n=7$ I am trying to determine in how many ways the intergers $1,2,\ldots,7$ can be divided in two groups with the same sum (here $14$). So one way to do that is $1+6+7 = 14 = 2+3+4+5$

Comment: A search on the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences yields entry http://oeis.org/A063865 , which tells you various ways to compute this number as well as an asymptotic formula for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously $1+2+\ldots+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ has to be an even number (hence that is possible only for $n\in\{0,3\}\pmod{4}$) and in such a case the answer is given by half the coefficient of $x^{\frac{n(n+1)}{4}}$ in the product
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+x^k\right). $$
See [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function) and [this article](https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/d10/d10.pdf). In the case $n=7$, the answer is just $\color{red}{4}$.